# Button Style with slim border

Tags: android, button, layout, dialog

I have a DialogFragment with Buttons that look like this:

[image]

How can I change the style of the buttons to look like this? 
[image]

I am extending DialogFragment, but would like to use the style that AlertDialog.Builder uses for the defaultPositive/negative buttons.

Comment: Change theme or give your dialog a custom layout.

Comment: Also hide Default Title bar and make your own Yellow title bar.

Comment: The style I want to use is the one that AlertDialog.Builder uses, but I can't find the name of the style.

Comment: Set `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo"></style>`
to your `Activity`

Comment: The activity uses a different style though. Can I not set the style for the button without setting the entire theme?

Answer (score 0):

It is default interface of android 2.3 below. You need external library to make it's interface become android 4.0 above style. You can use this [library](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) to do that.

Comment: No, this is not the default button style for 2.3.

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion in manifest file? And what is your Android version when running that dialog fragment (first image)?

Comment: Min and target are both 17.

Comment: The version is always 17 for this app. I only want it to look like the second style. Do I still need AppCompat for this? I am only interested in the buttons that don't have grey background as in the first picture.

Comment: edit: Your android device/emulator version? At the first image, it is Android 2.3 style. And for the second image, it is Holo style. You need to implement Holo style using such ActionbarSherlock or HoloEverywhere. This is application compatibility concern.

Comment: The device is also 17 only. What parameters do I need when doing setStyle(styleId, themeId) in my DialogFragment to get this to work?

Comment: Use ActionbarSherlock and implement its theme. How to use http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html and to implement its theme http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html. Have a nice day.

Comment: This must be possible without an additional library. The Dialogs built with AlertDialog.Builder have this style without any additional library.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

create a `xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/header_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="#FFFFBB33"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="@string/username" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/password"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

then in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // sign in the user ...
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();
}
```

then in the manifest

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
```

Comment: I am not using AlertDialog.Builder. I am extending DialogFragment.